# What does 赤道 mean in Japanese?

Tags: meaning

What does the Japanese word 赤道 mean? 
A Russian site claims that it means philosophical teaching.

Comment: voted to close as off-topic as it can be found on [online dictionary sites](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%B5%A4%E9%81%93&eng=&dict=edict) and by using [online translators](http://translate.google.com/#ja/en/%E8%B5%A4%E9%81%93).

Comment: I agree but Annix, please take a look at what we mean by off-topic on the meta site.  New correspondents are always welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is read as sekidō and means [equator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equator).